# Duvida sobre CONCAT SQL

Tags: sql-server, query

Entendi como funciona sobre `CONCAT` do `SQL-Server`, mas alguém pode me ajudar?

Por Exemplo: Tenho 3 tabelas: Equipe, Motor e Piloto.

usei concat com duas tabelas Equipe e Motor

```
Select Concat(Equipe,' - ', Motor) EQUIPE 
  From Pilotos PI, Equipes E, Motores M
 Where P.CODIGO_EQUIPE = E.CODIGO_EQUIPE
   And P.CODIGO_MOTOR = M.CODIGO_MOTOR
```

Veja o resultado abaixo deu certo, mas como faço excluir mesmo nome da 2ª coluna?

```
Resultado                       Quero resultado assim
EQUIPE                          EQUIPE
--------------------            -----------------------------
Cooper - Climax                 Cooper - Climax
Ferrari - Ferrari               Ferrari
Maserati - Maserati             Maserati
```

Aguardo.

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer um `CASE ... WHEN` para comparar quando os campos forem iguais faz o `CONCAT`, senão retorna só o campo:

```
SELECT  CASE
          WHEN Equipe <> Motor THEN Concat(Equipe,' - ', Motor)
          ELSE Equipe
        END as EQUIPE
  From Pilotos PI, Equipes E, Motores M
 Where P.CODIGO_EQUIPE = E.CODIGO_EQUIPE
   And P.CODIGO_MOTOR = M.CODIGO_MOTOR
```

Note que `WHEN Equipe <> Motor` está coparando diretamente os campos, se houver espaços, ou diferença na caixa (maiúsculas/minúsculas) não vai retorar o esperado.

Comment: Deu certo!!!!  Muito Obrigado, Ricardo!!!

Comment: não esqueça de aceitar a resposta ;)